# Can I run Windows 7 from a USB stick on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: windows-7, usb, macbook-pro

I have a MacBook Pro running OS X Lion (uses 100% of my Mac HD). I would like to play some Windows 7 games (e.g. Limbo, etc) but virtual machines are not good enough.

I wonder if it is possible to install Windows 7 in a USB stick (which minimal size?) and run from it, so that when the computer boots and detects the USB stick I can select between OS X and Windows 7, and more importantly, Windows 7 does not kill my OS X partition.

Comment: why not install it on a VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have enough disk space, [Boot Camp](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4818) is the solution for you. You get the full use of your Mac's hardware, and a decent Windows 7 performance.

Comment: my mac's HD is 100% dedicated to OSX. If I use bootcamp, do I need to reformat it completely or does bootcamp resize somehow the HD without loss of data?

Comment: The Bootcamp wizard will help you create a partition on your main disk - if you have enough free space. It's fairly painless - and reversible (i.e., at any time in the future, you can cancel the dual boot and absorb the Windows partition space back into the Mc partition)